# Json Loop Jquery each doesn't work "undefined"

Tags: jquery, json

I've got a problem with those data,

my json array data contains:

```
{"list_file":["{\"id\":\"511\",\"name\":\"Jellyfish.jpg\",\"projectId\":\"12539\",\"projectName\":\"project namessszd ddddzzde\",\"time\":\"1331843704\",\"size\":775702,\"timeRightFormat\":\"03\\\/15\\\/12 01:35:04 PM\",\"userFirstName\":\"Jerome\",\"userLastName\":\"Test\",\"userId\":\"8\"}","{\"id\":\"510\",\"name\":\"Hydrangeas.jpg\",\"projectId\":\"12539\",\"projectName\":\"project namessszd ddddzzde\",\"time\":\"1331843704\",\"size\":595284,\"timeRightFormat\":\"03\\\/15\\\/12 01:35:04 PM\",\"userFirstName\":\"Jerome\",\"userLastName\":\"Test\",\"userId\":\"8\"}","{\"id\":\"509\",\"name\":\"dudnzoizu ufoiuzio fueoifezuoiufifzeouofufzeoiuiofuz oife iofez.jpg\",\"projectId\":\"12539\",\"projectName\":\"project namessszd ddddzzde\",\"time\":\"1331843704\",\"size\":885242,\"timeRightFormat\":\"03\\\/15\\\/12 01:35:04 PM\",\"userFirstName\":\"Jerome\",\"userLastName\":\"Test\",\"userId\":\"8\"}"]}
```

when i loop through the elements like this

```
    $.each(data.list_file, function(i, file) {
        alert(file.id);
    });
```

I got undefined in the alert() box, but if i do just this instead

```
      $.each(data.list_file, function(i, file) {
        alert(file);
    });
```

I got the right json line.

Thank you

EDIT: with the entire array this time

Comment: because its simply treating it as a string and not as json? alert(typeof file); ?

Comment: Is that wrapped in a [], because what you have posted is not a valid JSON unless it is wrapped inside a []. If wrapped, then your function should work fine... http://jsfiddle.net/skram/F9Mrd/

Comment: ok i've edited the array with the full json code this time

Comment: The json you just updated with also doesn't look valid. Can you give us the actual output you get from the json file when you visit it in a browser?

Comment: this is the one that i get from the browser and it's valid, i just tested it with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: It is valid, but it isn't what you need it to be. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are making an ajax call. You need to specify the "json" datatype so that jquery will parse it as json.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        // ...
    }
})
```

UPDATE:

Your json array is an array of json strings, try changing that to an array of objects:

```
{ "list_file": [ "{...}" ]}
```

should be

```
{ "list_file": [ {...} ]}
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure that's something like this ;)

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the JSON in [], it'll work then.
What you have is a json list.

And check out this [Tinker.io](https://tinker.io/80af7/1)

If you parse the JSON you can then use the normal notation for accessing the objects
properties.

Validate the json [here!](http://jsonlint.com/)

Good luck!

Comment: my json is valid, actually i posted the entire array in edit ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you have inside list_file is a string and not an Object. Actually, you have 3 strings.. each an object... Try using a function like below,

```
$.each(data['list_file'], function(i, file) {
    alert(JSON.parse(file).id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is **not** a valid json

you should wrap it with brackets !

you have many objects which must be in an Array.

Fix this first. later check.

Comment: data is in brackets this is only a part of my json array

Comment: Wait, it is an array, but should be in []

Comment: @Jerome so upload all the Json